# "outside root element will be ignored" error when the syntax seems perfect in vue component

Tags: templates, vue.js, syntax, components

The following code seems ok at first but if examined in chrome debugger I see some error message "outside root element will be ignored"

The complete code is here:

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Royalblue/zk5L6am9/)

the template value of the Vue component certainly has only one top root containing div element, but strangely the debugger reports that it is not.
The following is the template definition part of the component:

```
        template: 
        `<div class="modal fade" v-show:"visible">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <slot name="header"></slot>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <slot></slot>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <slot name="footer"></slot>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>`,
```

The error message disappear if I enclose the whole template with additional redundant div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in using `v-show`

```
<div class="modal fade" v-show:"visible">
```

It should be:

```
<div class="modal fade" v-show="this.visible">
```

Most likely the extra `:` breaks the vuejs parser and ends up splitting your div declaration in two.